# apiary: Ignoring unrecognized block

Tags: rest, request, response, apiblueprint, apiary

I have the following definition in apiary for a service to post access rights:

```
## Access Right [/api/v0.3/accessrights/{id}/assign?isExternalKey=true]

### Assign access rights [Post]            

+ accessRightId (number)
+ personId (string)

+ Parameters
    + id (number) - ID of the Access Right in the form of an integer

+ Request (application/json)

            {
                "personId": "785"
            }

+ Response 201
```

Apiary tell me that the Request and the Response block are unrecognized. I tried to make the fields required, I made the parameter required, I changed the spelling of the fields, I removed the (application/json), i fiddled with the spacing. Nothing seems to help.
What is wrong with the Request and Response block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method names must be all-caps, as in the spec and on wire.

Therefore, the "Assign access rights" line should be written as follows:

```
### Assign access rights [POST]
```

Answer (score 0):

By switching the order of the blocks (from Parameters, Request, Response to Request, Response, Parameters), the request and response body are recognized:

```
## Access Right [/api/v0.3/accessrights/{id}/assign?isExternalKey=true]

### Assign access rights [Post]            

+ accessRightId (number)
+ personId (string)

+ Request (application/json)

            {
                "personId": "785"
            }

+ Response 201

+ Parameters
    + id (number) - ID of the Access Right in the form of an integer
```

I am not sure why that matters, but at least now the API validates as Valid API Blueprint.
The problem is solved!